# Question regarding Melissa-Harris Perry and the meaning of the word "hard"

Tags: word-usage

Last year, Melissa Harris-Perry, a liberal TV commentator, was famously quoted as saying that a person (in this case a Republican lawmaker) should perhaps not be allowed to be said to be a "hard worker" if he didn't do "hard work". The specific reference was to slavery and to the type of work that slaves once did. Mike Rowe, of "Dirty Jobs", among others critized her along political lines, but failed to mention that the word "hard" has different meanings depending upon how it is used.

Am I correct that Melissa was simply confusing "hard", the adverb, with "hard" the adjective? As I understand it, A "hard worker" is someone who works dilligently or industriously, usually over a long duration. This is the definition of the word when it is used as an adverb. On the other hand, "hard work", where the word is used as an adjective, describes work that is physically demanding or difficult, strenuous, or taxing, i.e "slave labor"

I just thought I would ask for a more expert opinion, and I have wondered if Melissa ever received comments or backlash from english language experts. The buzz following her remark was mostly political, but aside from all that, wasn't this just as much about grammar as it was about politics?

Hard workers do not necessarily do hard work!

Comment: When I think of "hard worker", I think of clichés that people put on their résumés. :P

Comment: I don't think there was any confusion.  Certainly there was a "play on words" relative to the meanings of "hard", but that's normal for politics.

Comment: The adverb form is "hardly", as in "hardly working". :)

Comment: Hello, Ken. 'Am I correct that Melissa was simply confusing "hard", the adverb, with "hard" the adjective?' No. If you look up 'hard' in a respectable dictionary (and such research is expected to accompany answers on ELU) you'll find that 'hard' is also used **as an adjective** in 'she's a hard worker': << _hard_   adj ...3.1 Putting a lot of energy into an activity.
_he'd been a hard worker all his life_ >>  {[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hard)}. // This is quite possibly a transferred usage. //// M H-P is selectively choosing senses here. Spinning. But ...

Comment: every one of us should always be aware of **all** the correct usages of a word.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Any word in particular, or do we get to choose one for ourselves?

Comment: @Hot Licks Harold Wilson's get-out-of-jail sense for 'pragmatic' is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in your analysis of the meanings of the phrases "hard worker" and "hard work". As you seem to understand, the former refers to a quality of the worker (diligence), while the latter refers to a quality of the work (difficulty).

As to whether Melissa was legitimately confused by the different usages of the word "hard", or trying to make a political point while playing off their similarity, who's to say? And as for backlash from the English language community, I couldn't find any within a few minutes of searching.

Comment: Are you also agreeing that 'Melissa was simply confusing "hard", the adverb, with "hard" the adjective'?